# SQL DB2 - conditional logic in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, db2, case

I need to pull back records based on a location ID, but I've got two fields that MAY contain the incoming criteria....

something like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE myVar = locationID
    IF LocationID = 0
      myVar = location2ID
```

this is a 'logical' example...

I think I can do

```
WHERE myVar = CASE WHEN locationID = 0 THEN location2ID ELSE locationID END
```

although I've read that CASE in a WHERE clause should be avoided...? why? or is this OK?
- either way it FAILS

```
WHERE CASE WHEN locationID=0 THEN location2ID=myVAr ELSE locationID=myVar END
```

also FAILS

thx

Sorry for the confusion lads - didn't mean to be "ambiguous" - looks like #2 will do what I want - but for the clarification requested here is the issue...

the table stores TWO locations, let's call then CURRENT_LOC and ORIGINAL_LOC... in most cases these will BOTH have data, but in some cases the 'thing' hasn't moved... so the CURRENT_LOC is '0'. MY issue is I'll be passing in a LOCATION ID, I want the records where CURRENT_LOC matches OR if the the CURRENT_LOC=0 then I ALSO want the ORIGINAL_LOC... where that matches...

does that help the discussion? I hope.

Comment: You've been given two answers, which have slightly different outlook on the problem.  Please disambiguate your question (by indicating what happens to `location2ID` when `locationID` is not 0), and accept the relevant answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`WHERE myVar = COALESCE(NULLIF(locationID, 0), location2ID)`

Alternatively,

```
WHERE (
       (locationID <> 0 AND myVar = locationID) 
       OR 
       (locationID = 0 AND myVar = location2ID)
      )
```